# Landscape Autopilot stuck at 77%

Tags: juju, openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I am trying to install the OpenStack Autopilot in my test lab and I am stuck. The MAAS has seen the nodes and is able to start deployment.However, when I start the OpenStack install in Landscape it gets stuck at 77%

This is with the latest available Autopilot release.
As you can see in the picture below all machines are hanging “add juju machine in an LXC”

In the syslog I have found this:

```
Mar  3 14:15:31 chief-chalk mongod.37017[5258]: Thu Mar  3 14:15:31.367 [conn48]  authenticate db: admin { authenticate: 1, nonce: "61b90d6dfe13bca2", user: "machine-0", key: "a1b501910b11b116d313168214d40500" }
Mar  3 14:15:31 chief-chalk mongod.37017[5258]: Thu Mar  3 14:15:31.367 [conn41]  authenticate db: admin { authenticate: 1, nonce: "bea4001cc8269ca0", user: "machine-0", key: "77291ade9456916207e1d737840aeaf3" }
Mar  3 14:15:31 chief-chalk mongod.37017[5258]: Thu Mar  3 14:15:31.370 [conn41]  authenticate db: admin { authenticate: 1, nonce: "aa302f0f39f3a62e", user: "machine-0", key: "d7f14f5ffbf445e2d2b7beca68e1d265" }
Mar  3 14:15:31 chief-chalk mongod.37017[5258]: Thu Mar  3 14:15:31.371 [conn48]  authenticate db: admin { authenticate: 1, nonce: "8761016b1ab6d010", user: "machine-0", key: "7d2bfbb01afeaf9f36559de03cac35f8" }
Mar  3 14:15:31 chief-chalk mongod.37017[5258]: Thu Mar  3 14:15:31.375 [conn48]  authenticate db: admin { authenticate: 1, nonce: "42c76307720ff38a", user: "machine-0", key: "539f36d66ded1cd82a5471f94aee3c5e" }
Mar  3 14:15:31 chief-chalk mongod.37017[5258]: Thu Mar  3 14:15:31.378 [conn48]  authenticate db: admin { authenticate: 1, nonce: "7d2d720cf2939e06", user: "machine-0", key: "fb5395ac525e1b0bb4fb0ee62d5e4722" }
Mar  3 14:15:31 chief-chalk mongod.37017[5258]: Thu Mar  3 14:15:31.386 [conn41]  authenticate db: admin { authenticate: 1, nonce: "730bac04c85843a0", user: "machine-0", key: "eadc49621866726d8c4176c179d8448f" }
Mar  3 14:15:31 chief-chalk mongod.37017[5258]: Thu Mar  3 14:15:31.388 [conn48]  authenticate db: admin { authenticate: 1, nonce: "c025e1ab24921a46", user: "machine-0", key: "bc6b075f5af6c9455b00a40f5cad8b75" }
Mar  3 14:15:31 chief-chalk mongod.37017[5258]: Thu Mar  3 14:15:31.390 [conn41]  authenticate db: admin { authenticate: 1, nonce: "e99f87e012ffd696", user: "machine-0", key: "5363b2d6be729ad2cd7cef8f9b2b9341" }
Mar  3 14:15:31 chief-chalk mongod.37017[5258]: Thu Mar  3 14:15:31.393 [conn48]  authenticate db: admin { authenticate: 1, nonce: "ae732f9554bb78cf", user: "machine-0", key: "7dd8f08e7eaff998c86a398d19623418" }
Mar  3 14:15:31 chief-chalk rsyslogd-2089: netstream session 0x7faf78369b40 will be closed due to error

Mar  3 14:15:31 chief-chalk rsyslogd-2089: netstream session 0x7faf783cadc0 will be closed due to error

^C
ubuntu@chief-chalk:/var/log$

ubuntu@chief-chalk:/var/log/juju$ sudo tail -f machine-0.log
2016-03-03 13:55:03 DEBUG juju.apiserver apiserver.go:275 -> [1] machine-0 6.120057ms {"RequestId":20,"Response":"'body redacted'"} Environment[""].WatchForEnvironConfigChanges
2016-03-03 13:55:03 DEBUG juju.network network.go:268 no lxc bridge addresses to filter for machine
2016-03-03 13:55:03 INFO juju.worker.machiner machiner.go:132 setting addresses for machine-0 to ["local-machine:127.0.0.1" "local-cloud:192.168.210.50" "local-machine:::1"]
2016-03-03 13:55:03 DEBUG juju.worker.logger logger.go:45 reconfiguring logging from "<root>=DEBUG" to "<root>=WARNING;unit=DEBUG"
2016-03-03 13:55:03 ERROR juju.state machine.go:1750 cannot update supported containers of machine 0: EOF
2016-03-03 13:55:03 ERROR juju.worker runner.go:223 exited "276561b1-e5fc-4361-8a99-8f0ce6c99744": failed to open state for environment 276561b1-e5fc-4361-8a99-8f0ce6c99744: cannot create index: EOF
2016-03-03 13:55:03 ERROR juju.worker runner.go:223 exited "api-post-upgrade": setting up container support: setting supported containers for machine-0: EOF
2016-03-03 13:55:03 ERROR juju.worker runner.go:223 exited "rsyslog": failed to write rsyslog certificates: cannot write settings: EOF
2016-03-03 13:55:03 ERROR juju.worker runner.go:223 exited "diskmanager": EOF
2016-03-03 13:55:03 ERROR juju.worker runner.go:223 exited "machiner": setting machine addresses: cannot set machine addresses of machine 0: EOF
^Cubuntu@chief-chalk:/var/log/juju$
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using vmware by any chance? Anyway, please hit the cancel button and Landscape will give you an opportunity to file a bug with logs attached. Then the problem can be properly diagnosed.

Comment: Hi Andreas! Yes, i am using VMware 5.5. MaaS can see the power devices and able to turn on/off the machines and I can deploy any image I want properly. Even the ssh key has been added properly to the deployment. When the landscape starts to deploy the openstack I can log into the nodes properly. I can see in the juju/all-machines.log a kind of infinite loop. It tries to read the packages and the config files again and again... Have you ever seen like this?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to allow promiscuous mode in the vSwitch, otherwise the LXC containers that we bring up inside the VMs will be blocked from the network.

Answer (score -1):

i have also the same exact issue. Running on esxi 5.5, MaaS works fine. Where should i look to give me a clue about the error? FYI, this is my first deployment using autopilot. If we had more information about the errors in the GUI, it would help to troubleshoot.